# how image processing detect photograph or real person in front of camara?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I planned to develop a software that can takes attendant (work , school) by face recognition as my final year project(FYP).(Just an Idea)

I have search through the net about the image processing library and i found out `OpenCv` is more well known as i found a lot of video for face recognition using `OpenCv` in youtube which will definitely help me a lot.(I'm totally new to image processing). Also, i will be using Visual Studio.

Here come the first problem, which is is it possible to detect that it is a photo or a real person is standing in front of the camera while taking the attending?

If yes, can you provide me some link or tutorial link for how image processing can detect 'photograph' and 'real person'?

As i said, I'm totally new to image processing and this is just an idea for my FYP

Or is the any open sources library that you recommend?

Comment: I think this is what you need. Eulerian Video Magnification
This software from MIT detects tiny movements invisible to the naked eye to detect if the persons face is "live" or a still image. http://people.csail.mit.edu/mrub/evm/#code

Answer (score 5):

[Eulerian Video Magnification](http://people.csail.mit.edu/mrub/vidmag/) can detect that it is a photo or a real person is standing in front of the camera but **it may not detect that it is a video or real person is standing in front of the camera**. Thus, the Face Recognition Authentication System which is based Eulerian Video Magnification can not be successfull when malicious user uses face video to rather than a real person face.

Here are my ideas to develop robust Face Recogition Authentication system;

1. You can use Multi-View Face Recognition to develop robust face authentication system. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rc5BBel8nmk) is a demo video of this technique and [here](https://www.ieee.org/searchresults/index.html?cx=006539740418318249752%3Af2h38l7gvis&cof=FORID%3A11&qp=&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&q=multi+view+face+recognition) are papers to get theoritical background. Also you can benefit from [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/face_recognition), [this](https://github.com/ajdroid/facetrackerapp), [this](https://github.com/marsbroshok/face-replace/blob/master/README.md) and [this](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/FaceTracker) when you start coding.
2. You can use **RANDOM** directions to detect that it is a photo/video or real person for example blink your eyes 3 times, move your eyebrow, look at the left side or look at the right side (multi-view face recognition will be used to recognize user's face when user look at the right or left) etc.

You should use these 2 ideas in your project for developing robust Face 
Recognition Authentication system.

Here is the scnario;

[image]